# memory leak in default_user_allocator_new_delete of boost 1.53

Tags: memory, boost, memory-leaks

I'm developing C++ based server application, and I'm using the latest Boost Library(1.53 version). Before I used 1.53 ver, I used 1.47 version.

The Question is, when I run my program with Debugging mode, Visual Leak Detector detects memory a leak from `default_user_allocator_new_delete`, which is NOT happened when using 1.47 version.

Have anyone experienced this situation? I need help!

Comment: boost is a collection of libraries, which libraries are you using in your project?

Comment: I'm using memory allocator things..

Comment: please edit your question to include this information